# C# Sending image over socket

Tags: c#, image, sockets

I'm trying to send a screenshot over a socket connected to the server, but i got the exception (on the server window) : Parameter is not valid, here is the code : 
Client side :

```
public static Image CaptureDesktop()
    {
        Rectangle bounds = default(Rectangle);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap screenshot = null;
        Graphics graph = default(Graphics);
        bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        screenshot = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
        graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return screenshot;
    }
    public static void PrepareImage()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(CaptureDesktop());
        Image f = (Image)bmp;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        f.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        _clientSocket.Send(ms.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("data sent");

    }
```

Server side :

```
public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int received = 0;

        try
        {
            received = current.EndReceive(AR);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            current.Close(); // Dont shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway
            _clientSockets.Remove(current);
            return;
        }

        byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
        try
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(recBuf);
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
        }


    }
```

The exception is at this line : Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

What is wrong in my code ?
Thank you :)

Comment: Data received at server may be partial image, You've to prefix the length and buffer the partially received data etc. check [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) out.

Comment: Exactly Sriram Sakthivel, it shows a small part of the title bar, and a lot of MessageBox that contains the exception, but i did not understand what is on the link you sent :/

Comment: You have to store the received bytes until you receive full data. That link will guide you to do. [part3 of that link](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html)

Comment: Here is what i i understood : I store each received bytes in the PacketProtocole, when all the bytes are received, then the image is complete, is it correct ?

Comment: Well, not exactly. You store the data into the buffer and wait until you receive fully by checking received length with the prefix(which has a length of the image). Is that clear?

Comment: Ah yes it's clear now, but how to check is the length are fully or not ? I'm so sorry for taking your time :/

Comment: I think i should compare ms.Length and Packetprotocol.bytesReceived no ?